# Compare object stored as value in hashmap

Tags: java, performance

I am having a hashMap which stores my values like that:

```
{10997=Event [Numb=0007449001, date=07.02.2008], 10998=Event [Numb=0007449001, date=08.04.2008], ...
```

As you can see the key is a integer and the value is an Event Object which has a numeric value and a date, which is saved as a String.

I want to compare the numeric value of the map to another value with an if statment.

I tried:

```
if(numericVal==eventMap.get(i).toString()) {
```

However that does not really work. How to get the value easily out of the HashMap and of the Object?

I appreciate your answer!

**UPDATE**

By easily I mean performance orientated, because I have to process `a lot` of values.

Comment: Do you have a way to get the numeric value from your Event object? Something like eventMap.get(i).getNumericValue() ?

Comment: you want to compare numerical value with what of map? Is it `key` values of map or `Numb` of `Event`?

Comment: All `Map`s have a method called `keySet()` that returns a `Set` of keys.  You could then iterate through them.  However, if all you want to do is tell if a key is in your Map, then you can use the `contains()`.  Being a `HashMap` it should be the most optimal way to see if your `HashMap` contains a particular key.

Comment: `==` seems not right here `== eventMap.get(i).toString()`. Also what is your `Event` class? Does it have methods to get value of `Numb`?

Comment: Use method `equals` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 1):

first off; do not compare `String`s with `==` use `equalsIgnoreCase()` instead (or just `equals()` if the casing matters)

second; consider giving your `Event` a [`compareTo()`](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=10) and while you are at it an [`equals()`](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17) and a [`hashCode()`](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074996/hashcode-and-equals-method-in-java-object---a-pragmatic-concept.html).

Once you got the components in place and why they should be there, you'll realize what you want to do is possible in a much more elegant way.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you are trying to compare the actual numeric value within your `EventObject`

Therefore your `EventObject` has to have an accesor to it.

Lets say your `EventObject` looks something like:

```
public class EventObject {    
    private String numericValue;
    private String date;

    public EventObject(String numericValue, String date) {
        this.numericValue = numericValue;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getNumericValue() {
        return numericValue;
    }

    public void setNumericValue(String numericValue) {
        this.numericValue = numericValue;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

}
```

From there now accessing the `numericValue` from a `HashMap` should be as easy as:

```
HashMap<Integer,EventObject> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(10997,new EventObject("0007449001", "07.02.2008"));

int keyMap = 10997;  //for sake of making obvious this is Key and not numericValue 
String numValue = hashMap.get(keyMap).getNumericValue();
```

A comparison then can be done by:

```
if("0007449001".equals(map.get(10997).getNumericValue())) {
    System.out.println("The Date I have is: " + map.get(10997).getDate());
}
```

Which will get you:

```
The Date I have is: 07.02.2008
```